# Connection Monitoring with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to monitor the active connections connected to my node.js server. I've seen NodeFly can do this, but I would like to have a tool locally installed on my server (ubuntu).

Is there any (maybe free) software/app to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything doing that out of the box, but assuming you have an express app, you could start with:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

...

app.get('/status', function (req, res) {
  exec('lsof +p `pgrep node` | grep TCP', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    req.send(stdout);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was searching for something like the tomcat manager...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything like that. I had a similar need and ended up tracking my open connections manually. You could also try something like my new example.

Comment: Thanks mate, I guess I go for nodefly.com. Event though I'm not feeling comfortable with sending such data into the cloud, it currently seems to be the best solution for what I wanted.